# 2 submit buttons - different queries,

Tags: java, html, forms, jsp

I have a simple question and I can't find the answer by myself, so here it is.

Let's assume I have one simple index.html in which I have a form with 2 submit buttons. The action to those buttons is mapped to action.jsp. What I want to do is, if I click on the first submit button I want a query of type "SELECT * FROM USER WHERE ID = 1" and when I click on the second submit button I want a query of type "SELECT * FROM USER WHERE ID = 2". Can i do that in a single JSP file? How to do the check whether the first or the second submit button is pressed in the action.jsp - is that possible? Thanks!

Comment: Retrieve the attribute  value of button on action.jsp and depending upon the value take the action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do both the operations on same JSP page.
Lets say you have two buttons like :

```
<input type="submit" name="bt1"/>
<input type="submit" name="bt2"/>
```

Now you can check their button click like :

```
if(request.getParamater("bt1")!=null)
{
     //your first query
}
if(request.getParameter("bt2")!=null)
{
    //your second query
}
```

Also make sure that form action should be the same JSP page on which it is declared

Answer (score 1):

try using 2 forms, 1 form for each button.

or try using button only and create a function to handles it `onclick()`

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you can use two submit buttons in single`JSP` page.

Try this

```
<INPUT type="submit" name="bsubmit" value="Submit 1">

<INPUT type="submit" name="bsubmit" value="Submit 2">
```

Now when you create the script, these unique values will help us to figure out which of the submit buttons was pressed.

For example

Following is a sample Active Server Pages script to check for the submit button.

```
if Request.Form("bsubmit") = "Submit 1" then
btnID = "1"
elseif Request.Form("bsubmit") = "Submit 2" then
btnID = "2"
```

At server page you can write something like this